# What is the correct syntax for CSS rule @supports used with pseudo-class in Sass

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, sass

I am trying to use the rule @supports with pseudo-class :focus-visible in sass.
I can't seem to get it working. Does it have to do anything with the sass version ?

My code is like this:

```
  @supports not selector(&:focus-visible)
     &:focus
       outline: 1px solid white
       outline-offset: 3px
```

I tried it also removing "selector" and still doesn't work.

```
  @supports not (&:focus-visible)
     &:focus
       outline: 1px solid white
       outline-offset: 3px
```

The code compiles correctly but it appears to bypass the code @support and goes directly to the next line, and the rest of the code :focus works fine. I don't want it to work as standalone code, I want it to work with @support.

Comment: Try selecting that element you are selecting in developer tools (F12), and see if there is a small symbol next to the compiled CSS for that element. It usually tells you what is wrong if you mouse over it

Comment: [Try this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@supports#testing_for_the_support_of_a_selector) under Testing for the support of a selector